# Can I use an array formula to help pull data into a table

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to figure out an array formula that will will filter information and return any cells that meet that criteria.

I need it to show me what urbo #'s (cells in column A) that have Dave Barber as the designer (Column M) but only are either in Design Draft or Design Revision as the first step needed (Column R)

I would love some help trying to figure out the formula so that I can figure out the exact urbo numbers (column A) that fit the above criteria for my whole spreadsheet.

Thank you!!

Sadly I can not post a picture of the spreadsheet bc my reputation is low and I do not know another way to show you the spreasheet :(

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace "place urbo # input here" with the appropriate input.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A, "place urbo # input here", M:M, "Dave Barber", R:R, {"Design Draft", "Design Revision"}))
```

The above formula will give you the total number of the instances where the urbo # appears. If you instead need to add-up all of the urbo #s that fall into this criteria, you can just sub-out the COUNTIF with SUMIFS:

```
 =SUM(SUMIFS(A:A, "place urbo # input here", M:M, "Dave Barber", R:R, {"Design Draft", "Design Revision"}))
```